# WooCommerce prevent direct url access to checkout page, allow access only if user clicked "checkout" button in the cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've customized my WooCommerce cart page with additional input fields for each product. Some of these extra inputs are required and must be filled before proceeding to checkout. Currently, users can bypass this by entering the checkout URL directly. I want to restrict access so users can ONLY reach the checkout page by clicking the 'checkout' button on the cart page. If someone tries to access the checkout URL directly, I'd like them redirected back to the cart page to fill the required inputs (also so they are able to see the optional inputs and fill some of them if they'd like). How can I implement this?

**Edit:** I understand that I could check if the required inputs are filled and if so allow access to the "checkout" page otherwise redirect to the "cart" page. However, I prefer a solution where direct URL access to the checkout page is prevented entirely, and access is only granted if the user clicks the "checkout" button on the cart page. This is because some products may have all its extra inputs optional, and if the user accessed the checkout page directly, they might miss the opportunity to fill in those inputs (if they wanted to).

Comment: using woocommerce_checkout_process you can compare what data you have in your cart items and redirect to cart page if needed.

Comment: @Snuffy thanks for your reply but there're some products that there extra inputs are all optional so in this case the compare will pass since there're no required inputs. and the "checkout" page will open normally. However in this case the user didn't got the chance to see these optional inputs that the user might wanted to fill them.

so I want to restrict direct url access to checkout page regardless, and allow access only if user clicked "checkout" button in the cart page

Comment: Most users wont type url to skip cart so make sure there is no direct link to checkout like in the mini cart . This should be enough without any coding.

Comment: @Snuffy thanks I already removed the checkout link from the mini cart. And I know that most users won't type the checkout page url directly in the browser's address bar. But still there might be a few users who will do

Comment: Hi @Amjed. Have you checked [prevent direct access to a page in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65637441/10497022). This might also help you: [Disable direct access to a wordpress page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57193946/10497022). Here they use `template_redirect` hook and `wp_get_referer` function for redirect on form submission button.

Comment: Hi @Richard thank you so much! Yes! finally I was able to achieve this using  `template_redirect` hook and `wp_get_referer` function also thank you for the second SO answer link :)